# What is the longest working cubesat?

Tags: artificial-satellite, cubesat, record

For example VZLUSAT-1 is 5 years old and it is still working.

Comment: BugSat-1 was on the same payload launcher as UNISAT-6 and is also still active.

Comment: Not specifically a cubesat SAUDISAT 1C, was launched in 2002 and is still active. The list is really quite long for cubesats (the first launched in 2003) - CANX-2 for example is still listed as operational (when over its ground station) and that was launched in 2008. (the ones I listed earlier are from 2014)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under the specific CubeSat design specification, one of the earliest CubeSat launches was on 30 June 2003 from Plesetsk, Russia, with Eurockot Launch Services's Multiple Orbit Mission. The CubeSats were injected into a Sun-synchronous orbit and included the Danish AAU CubeSat and DTUSat, the Japanese XI-IV and CUTE-1, the Canadian Can X-1, and the US Quakesat.

According to this: https://opensea.io/assets/ethereum/0xb4612c2f7b7dac79e176a1d8513c9a5b3a33e868/14

> The first mission was a multiple launch of 6 CubeSats using a Rokot-KM rocket, a remake of the old SS-19 Stiletto soviet intercontinental ballistic missile. The CubeSats were: AAU-Cubesat Aalborg University Cubesat (DK), CanX 1 Canadian Advanced Nanospace eXperiments (CA), CUTE 1 CUbical Tokyo institute of technology Engineering satellite (JP), DTUSat Danmarks Tekniske Universitet Satellite (DK), QuakeSat (USA) and XI-IV (JP).
>
> CubeSat XI-IV (Sai Four), the OSCAR 57, is still active.

CUTE-1 is also considered still active.

As of 2022, makes these 2 the oldest CubeSats still active.